# context does not get overwritten with new value

Tags: python, django

I try to add or overwrite some context values in a detail view.
However the results are not displayed on the page, any idea how this is possible ??

Latest django version.

id and amount are part of the model.
amount should be overwritten and drunk should be added.

```
class EntryDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'entry'
    model = models.Entry
    template_name = 'web/entry_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['amount'] = "what shall we do with the drunken sailer"
        context['drunk'] = "so drunken"
        return context
```

The template contains :

```
<div class="jumbotron">
id : {{ entry.id }} <br>
amount: {{ entry.amount }}<br>
drunk: {{ entry.drunk }}<br>
</div>
```

I get :

```
id : 1
amount: 5
drunk:
```

while i would expect

```
id : 1
amount: what shall we do with the drunken sailer
drunk: so drunken
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not overwrite the keys for the entity. The `context` does *not* contain the items `id`, `amount` and `drunk`. It contains a key `'entry'` that maps to the `Entry` object that is fetched, and that has as attributes `amount` and `drunk`.

You can override these attributes, for example with:

```
class EntryDetailView(DetailView):
    context_object_name = 'entry'
    model = models.Entry
    template_name = 'web/entry_detail.html'

    def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        entry = context['entry']
        entry.amount = 'what shall we do with the drunken sailer'
        entry.drunk = 'so drunken'
        return context
```

It is however usually *not* a good idea to override the attributes of a model object.

With the *old* context, you can render the data as:

```
<div class="jumbotron">
id : {{ entry.id }} <br>
amount: {{ amount }}<br>
drunk: {{ drunk }}<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is so true, I was mislead-ed in the manual where similar is posted as an example here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-simple/